# Ruby Sinatra streaming via Thin only works locally

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, streaming, sinatra, thin

I'm working on streaming plain text back to the client as outlined in http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/streaming.html. It works fine when I curl the page locally, but comes back as one big chunk when I curl remotely.

The Sinatra code is very simple:

```rb
get '/stream-test' do
  stream do |out|
    out << "message 1\n"
    sleep(1)
    out << "message 2\n"
  end
end
```

I've tried using thin and puma. Running on an AWS EC2 instance and hitting the Elastic IP address, using the exact same command on both the instance and locally:

```
$curl -i "http://<elastic-ip>:8080/stream-test"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: rack.session=*******; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

message 1
message 2
```

Thanks

Comment: How is this deployed? What web server?

Comment: I've tried both Thin https://github.com/macournoyer/thin and Puma http://puma.io/